# getting ConnectionDoesNotExist error when attempting to migrate mysql database in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, connection

here's my code in django settings.py for the database:

```
DATABASES= {
    'defualt': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'cameronkc',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '123456',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': ''
    }
}
```

here's the error im recieving when executing >**python manage.py migrate** in command prompt

```
django.db.utils.ConnectionDoesNotExist: The connection default doesn't exist
```

Comment: try add 'PORT': 3306 and try again. 3306 is default port for mysql. And you know your user, password, and  'name' database is correct?

Answer (score 2):

You misspelled default in your `DATABASES` dict.  Change `'defualt'` to `'default'`.

Comment: man, nothing like a simple typo that wastes a couple hours of my time. lesson learned. I appreciate you.

Comment: Do you use IDE at all?